# Proving whether a matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-verification, inverse

Below I will prove that the matrix $A$  is not invertible, using the linear transformation $T:V\to W$ that corresponds to $L_A$ (over a field $\mathbb{F}$).

The reason for posting is proof verification, and sharing a bit of knowledge in case it already is correct. I couldn't really find this method to check invertibility of matrices anywhere else; mostly, people refer to the determinant or just Gaussian elimination (without the isomorphism/bijection part which to me is an interesting insight).

***Proof:***

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}
  6 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 \\
  2 & 8 & 4
 \end{pmatrix}$, then we can see that $T:\mathbb{F}^3\to \mathbb{F}^3$ is the linear transformation that corresponds to $L_A$, and that a row echelon form of $A$ is 
$\begin{pmatrix}
  6 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}$.

We know that $dim(V)=dim(W)=3$ and that $dim(V)=rank(T)+null(T)$. 
From the row echelon form of $A$ we can see that $rank(A)=rank(T)=2$ so that $dim(V)=2+null(T).$

However, for the matrix to be invertible, we need the linear transformation be bijective.

If  $dim(V)=dim(W)=3$ and $rank(A)=2$ we see that $rank(T)\neq dim(W)\implies R(T)\neq W$ so the mapping is not onto and thus not bijective.

We also see that $null(T) = 3-2=1\neq0$ so the mapping is not one-to-one and thus not bijective.

In either case, we see that the matrix $A$ is not invertible.

Comment: Are you asking whether the proof is correct?

Comment: It is easier to just take the determinant, no?

Comment: @AnderAguirre basically, and sharing a bit of knowledge in case it already is correct. Couldn't really find this method for insight in invertibility of matrices anywhere else, mostly people refer to the determinant or just gaussian elimination (without the isomorphism/bijection part which to me is an interesting insight)

Comment: Or, by inspection $\;\begin{pmatrix}
  6 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 2 & 1 \\
  2 & 8 & 4
 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  1 \\
  -2
 \end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix}
  0 \\
  0 \\
  0
 \end{pmatrix}\,$ so the transformation is not injective.

Comment: I think dxiv has the answer you are looking for